# Jquery/CSS: How to apply addClass with a delay of 1 sec on mouseenter event.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my code to addClass which is working.
But when I try to use delay or setTimeout functions, it is NOT working.

I don't want to use webkit attributes in CSS.

Please advise if anybody faced this issue earlier.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#table_Id tr td').mouseenter(function(){ 
               $(this).parent('tr').addClass('blueBgColor'); 
            });
  });
```

Comment: how are you using setTimeout function???

Comment: add class will add the class on every event you might consider adding the class if it not exists toggleClass('classname',true)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout), it calls a function or executes a code snippet after a specified delay.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table_Id tr td').mouseenter(function() {
        var self = this; //Cache this in a variable
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(self).parent('tr').addClass('blueBgColor');
        }, 1000); //Here delay in milliseconds
    });
});
```

EDIT: Usage of `bind`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table_Id tr td').mouseenter(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).parent('tr').addClass('blueBgColor');
        }.bind(this), 1000); //Here delay in milliseconds
    });
});
```

Comment: Should that not be `var self = $(this);` ?

Comment: @Carl, Why can't I use `$(self)`?

Comment: If you headed this way, it's better to pass it to the timeout like this :  setTimeout(function(){ .... }.bind(this), 1000);

Comment: @YairTavor did you try to bind it like that? that doesn't work

Comment: @YairTavor, There are different ways of acheving same thing

Comment: @Satpal - sorry, your right - was just skimming & didn't notice you were adding the $() around the `self`. I'm just used to seeing it the other way around.

Comment: It was really a very quick answer. It worked for me perfectly. Thanks a lot Satpal.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Another alternative is the queue function after jquery's delay. I added a link to your answer in my answer though.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. If I want to change the bgcolor of row only after hovering(meaning...i have a tooltip on each row. I want to change the color only after viewing a tooltip) for 1 or 2 seconds. How to achieve this?  With my current code, the color changes for all rows whereever my mouse-cursor touches after 1 second delay.  My objective is to distinguish what all rows have been viewed(meaning viewing the tooltip). To put it simple. I want to change the color of row only after having my cursor for atleast 1 or 2 sec. Sorry for lengthy explanation. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

hey i have created a jsfiddle for your problem...

code:-

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#table_Id tr td').mouseenter(function() {
         var td = $(this);
         setTimeout(function() {
             td.parent('tr').addClass('blueBgColor');
         }, 1000);
     });
 });
```

Working example:-

http://jsfiddle.net/L7S37/14/

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myTimeout;
  $('#table_Id tr td').on("mouseenter", function(){
    var that = $(this);
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
      that.parent('tr').addClass('blueBgColor');
    }, 1000);
  });
  // Also if you need, you can do:
  $('#table_Id tr td').on("mouseleave", function(){
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
  });
});
```

**OR:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myTimeout;
  // use event.target
  $('#table_Id tr td').on("mouseenter", function (e) {
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
      $(e.target).parent('tr').addClass('blueBgColor');
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use toggle class if not exists otherwise on every mouseenter the class will be added over and over:

```
$('#table_Id tr td').mouseenter(function(){
    $td = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){$td.toggleClass('addedClass',true)},'1000');
});
```

[js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/65J69/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 $('#table_Id tr td').mouseenter(function(){
    var $this = $(this); 
    setTimeout(function () {
           $this.parent('tr').addClass('blueBgColor');        
   }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: You'd want to set `$(this)` in to a variable outside of the setTimeout's scope, as the `$(this)` you access inside it will refer to the setTimeout itself rather than the element triggering mouseenter event.

Comment: Ah yea, hadn't refreshed. Your solution now looks correct to my eye :) [Edit: just to note, I'm not the downvoter]

Comment: no problem .. but I appreciate that you commented the right thing ..:)

Comment: With this, we are able to delay the applying of addClass. If I want to change the bgcolor of row only when we hover for 2 seconds? How to acheive this?

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$('#table_Id tr td').off('mouseenter').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var element = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(element).parent('tr').addClass('blueBgColor');
    }, 1000); /*delay for 1 sec*/
});
```

Comment: Just to note: You'd want to set $(this) in to a variable outside of the setTimeout's scope, as the $(this) you access inside it will refer to the setTimeout itself rather than the element triggering mouseenter event.

Comment: Incorrect! It will add classes to all trs in the table!